# How to correctly render one line code blocks on Firefox?

Tags: html, css

While trying to render a single line of code in a code block the layout is too close to the line numbers (this only happens on Firefox):
[image: Example of error for one line of code]

The html code for this is automatically rendered by Hugo and it looks like this (I removed the color highlighting classes):

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre>
          <code>
            <span>1
            </span>
          </code>
        </pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>
          <code>
            <span>actual code goes here
            </span>
          </code>
        </pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I noticed that if, instead of:

```
<span>1
</span>
```

I remove the new line like this:

```
<span>1</span>
```

The code renders properly. The problem is that I am unable to change the html since it comes from Hugo. I would only be able to change the css for this. I also tried using the `white-spacing` property which corrects the behavior for one line block, but makes every line render on the same row for the multiple line block.

Is there a Firefox specific css property that could help me with this?

The code structure for a multi-line example which renders correctly:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <pre>
      <code>
        <span>1
        </span><span>2
        </span>
      </code>
    </pre>
  </td>
  <td>
    <pre>
      <code>
        <span>actual code goes here</span>
      </code>
    </pre>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but you can use some pseudo-elements as a quick fix.
Either:

```css
pre code span::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
    <span>1
    </span>
  </code>
</pre>
<pre>
  <code>
    <span>actual code goes here
    </span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Or just use the `content` with spaces:

```css
pre code span::before {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
    <span>1
    </span>
  </code>
</pre>
<pre>
  <code>
    <span>actual code goes here
    </span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this best represents the behavior I want. What should happen to the first example (one line code) is what currently happens to the second example (multiple line code). The spacing between the line number and the text should be the same.

Comment: @OldDew It is by no means a nice solution but if you want to achieve this by CSS only, I'm not really sure if it can be done with any other way.

Comment: A fix that was almost good was adding the 'white-spacing' property which, from what I read, ignores white spaces or new lines. That way I could ignore the new line added after the span content, but it had the side effect of removing all the white spacings inside the code tag. Additionally, this looks perfect on Chrome, could you think of something that's unsupported on Firefox that would lead to this behaviour?

Comment: @OldDew Is each line of code included in a `<span>`? If so, you could use the `white-space: nowrap;` along with `content: ' ';`. You can check the compatibility in [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/)

Comment: In the table, one <td> contains all the line numbers and the other <td> contains the actual code on each line.

Comment: @OldDew yes but in what structural format? Please post a multi-line code example html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240996/discussion-between-olddew-and-george-chond).